# How to count occurrences no matter its case?

Tags: awk, count, ignore-case

table

```
chr10   10482   10484   0   11  +   CA
chr10   10486   10488   0   12  +   ca
chr10   10487   10489   0   13  +   Ca
chr10   10490   10492   0   13  +   cA
chr10   10491   10493   0   12  +   CT
chr10   10494   10496   6.66667 15  +   ca
chr10   10495   10497   6.66667 15  +   cc
```

I would like the count the number of lines in column 7 where "CA" can be found regardless of the any of the two letters being in upper or lower case.

The desired output would be 5.

The two commands (below) give an empty output

```
cat table | awk ' $7 ==/^[Cc][Aa]/{++count} END {print count}'

awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1} $7==/"CA"/ {++count} END {print count}' table
```

The below command returns a value of 1

```
awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1} END {if ($7=="CA"){++count} {print count}}' table
```

Note: my actual table is tens of millions of lines long, thus I do not want to write a table as an intermediate in order to count.  (I need to repeat this task for other files too).

Comment: Please note that IGNORECASE is a feature of GNU awk (gawk) only, and is not available in other awk implementations.

Comment: Also, would `grep -c -w -i 'ca$' table` not be sufficient? Or are you building other functionality into your awk script besides counting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a little problem in your syntax: you either say `var == "string"` or `var ~ regexp`, but you are saying `var ~ /"string"/`. Using the correct combination makes your command work:

```
$ awk '$7 ~ /^[Cc][Aa]/{++count} END {print count+0}' file
5
$ awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1} $7=="CA" {++count} END {print count+0}' file
5
```

Also, you may want to use `toupper()` (or `tolower()`) to check this, instead of using the `IGNORECASE` flag:

```
awk 'toupper($7) == "CA" {++count} END {print count+0}' file
```

Note the trick to print `count + 0` instead of just `count`. This way, we cast the variable to `0` if it wasn't set before. With this, it will print `0` whenever there was no matches; if we would just `print count`, it would return an empty string.

Comment: I have used the syntax awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1} $7=="CA" {++count} END {print count}' file and this has indeed worked